# QGIS to Illustrator: file cannot be opened because there is not enough RAM

Tags: qgis, vector, export, illustrator

I am having trouble getting my files to transfer or export to a vector file. When I open the file in Adobe illustrator there is a lot of information missing. I have tried to "save selection as a vector..." I have all my layer selected. I tried selecting individual layers, all the layers at once, I selected the layers individually.

Next I tried to play with the CRS pull down menu. I used all the options and still get no results. I finally got what may be a file but when i open it in illustrator I get an error message that says "file cannot be opened because there is not enough RAM, I have 12 gigs of RAM, should not be a problem.

Am I missing something? A plug-in?

Comment: I am a little unsure why you are opening a spatial file in Adobe Illustrator. Can you tell us what file type you are working with and what export type you would like?

Answer (score 3):

have you tried to export to pdf via print composer and to import this pdf into illustrator?

Comment: in composer, how do you add a map? I see the icon but when I click on it nothing happens???

Comment: click on the 13th. button from the left (the mapsymbol with a green plus) and drag a rectangle on the canavas

Comment: If you are looking to export the vectors for cartography purposes, try the SimpleSVG plugin.  This plugin will export all the vectors in QGIS into a single SVG file.  When you open the file each vector layer in the QGIS Table of Contents will be its own layer in the SVG.  The layers will also have the colouring and lines styling from QGIS.  I have not used Illustrator with the SVG files, but they open great in InkScape.